# Dictionary Object confusion from jQuery to Django!

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json, object

I'm attempting to send a dictionary from jQuery to Django using a getJSON call:

```
jQuery.getJSON(URL,JSONData,function(returnData){});
```

The JSONData object is formatted as follows:

```
JSONData = {
     year:2010101,
     name:"bob",

     data:{
          search:[jim,gordon],
          register:[jim],
          research:[dave],
          }
}
```

This is put together programmatically but looks fine.

Once passed to Django the "year" and "name" objects are as expected.  The data object however contains the following keys/values - "search[0]":"jim", "search[1]":"gordon","register[0]":"jim","research[0]":"dave", rather than the expected "search":(array of data), "register":(array of data), "research":(array of data).

Similar things happen if I use objects in place of the arrays.

Is this an issue with Django's interpretation of the object?

Any idea how I might correct this...cleanly?

EDIT:

I have now simplified the data to make testing easier:

```
JSONData = { 
     year:2010101, 
     name:"bob", 
     search:[jim,gordon], 
     register:[jim], 
     research:[dave], 

}
```

Comment: Can you also post how you handle the data in your view?

Comment: at this stage I'm literally returning request.GET.keys()

Comment: for now I've conceded defeat, instead of a list I'm using a string and splitting it on the django end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.GET` is not an instance of a normal python `dict`, but of the [django class `QueryDict`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), that can deal with multiple values for one key. If you need multiple values for a key returned as a list you have to use [`getList`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)!

EDIT: Also have a look at this [jQuery parameter settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)!

Comment: Nope, the problem still remains that the data has been split up incorrectly and the key names mangled. eg request.GET.getlist("Search") should give me the associated list, instead it returns nothing. request.GET.getlist("Search[0]") gives me the single value as above.

Comment: Aha! had to set traditional = True in the parameter settings.  Nice work!